# How to get all the properties of items in List and convert them to a GridColumn using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, gridview, properties, blazor

I'm writing an application where I obtain data like this(the string "SettingsSubPage" represents the name of the data model, in this case "User"):

```
[Parameter]
public string SettingsSubPage { get; set; }

Results = ApiProvider.GetAll(System.Type.GetType(SettingsSubPage));
```

[image]

From this data I want to show every property except "UserRoles", therefore i created an attribute that makes it able to hide data:

Attribute:

```
public class HideInTableAttribute : Attribute
{
    
}
```

Modal(User) class:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "This is not a valid email adress")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Password must be between 5 and 50 characters")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }

    */ HERE WE HIDE THE PROPERTY /*
    [HideInTable]
    public List<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to obtain a list of these properties except "UserRoles" and make them GridColumns so I get a list of GridColumns. An example how to make them GridColumns(used in other class) can be done like this:

```
.Select(x => new GridColumn()
                    {
                        Field = x.Name,
                        HeaderText = x.Name,
                        TextAlign = TextAlign.Center
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

So what I need is a LINQ query that obtains the Properties of "SettingsSubpage" model and convert them into GridColumns and put them into a list, what I've tried so far is this:

```
List<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo> list = System.Type.GetType(SettingsSubPage).GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(true).OfType<HideInTableAttribute>().Any()).ToList();
```

However this is giving me this error:

[image]

Hope someone can help, thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry but I don't quite understand the relationship between `SettingsSubpage` and the `User` class. Don't you try to get the properties of the `User` class?

Comment: Yes, but application is dynamically build. So when I switch from pages I'm passing a parameter that represents the Model, in this case the url is: settings/User. Once landed on the application I parse the User to the class like this: System.Type.GetType(SettingsSubPage)

Comment: Is `SettingsSubPage` a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your type is in another Assembly, you need to provide the AssemblyQualifiedName in typeName parameter of GetType.

ex.

```
 var mytype= Type.GetType("DnetAdminDashboard.DesktopNavigation.NavigationMenu, DnetAdminDashboard, Version=1.3.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null", true);
```

NavigationMenu is the class

if you dont know the AssemblyQualifiedName, see how to get it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname?view=netcore-3.1#System_Type_AssemblyQualifiedName

also you can load the Assembly and then get the type.

DnetAdminDashboard is the Assembly

```
 var assm = Assembly.Load("DnetAdminDashboard");
 var myType = assm.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "NavigationMenu");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this once:

```
var propsList = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Where(x => !Attribute.IsDefined(x, typeof(HideInTableAttribute)))
                .ToList();
```

> Here T is the Class name